# Radius of convergence of power series $\sum z^{n!}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

How to find the radius of convergence of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n!}\ ?$$
It seems to me that $R=1$ but I dont know how.

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy-Hadamard formula?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer the problem I didnt know anything about "sup"

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: if you can solve it by (the Cauchy-Hadamard formula) with some explanation for (sup)

Comment: Let $a_k = 1$ if $k = n!$ for some $n > 1$, $a_1 = 2$, and $a_k = 0$ otherwise, so the sum is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$. Then $\sqrt[k]{a_k} = 0$ if $k$ is not a factorial, and $\sqrt[k]{a_k} = 1$ if $k > 1$ is a factorial. So $\limsup \sqrt[k]{a_k} = 1$.

Comment: This might be closed soon but, before it is, or not, let us mention that neither Cauchy-Hadamard formula nor the ratio test are needed to solve this, only the definition of the RoC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the ratio test: 
$$
\frac{\lvert z^{(n+1)!}\rvert}{\lvert z^{n!}\rvert}=\lvert z\rvert^{(n+1)!-n!}=\lvert z\rvert^{(n+1)n!-n!}=\lvert z\rvert^{n\cdot n!}.
$$
Since $n\cdot n!\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, we get that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\lvert z^{(n+1)!}\rvert}{\lvert z^{n!}\rvert}=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if }\lvert z\rvert<1\\1 & \text{if }\lvert z\rvert=1\\ \infty & \text{if }\lvert z\rvert>1\end{cases},
$$
so that we get convergence for $\lvert z\rvert<1$ and divergence for $\lvert z\rvert>1$. Thus, the radius of convergence is, as you suggest, $1$.