# Variable Transform of Power Series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I realize that this question is a [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491088/how-to-find-radius-of-convergence-for-sum-n-0-inftyzn), but I have a different question. I am asked to find the radius of convergence $R$ of

> $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n!}$

I want to put it in the form $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k z^k$, as this is the form demanded by all the theorems I can use (note, I do not have the ratio test available to calculate $R$). I though to choose $k = n!$, and then $c_k = 1$ for all $k$. However, Daniel Fischer's comment says otherwise. So my question is, why is

$c_k = \begin{cases} 
1, ~if~k=n! ~for~some ~n>1 \\
2, ~if~k=1 \\
0, ~otherwise
\end{cases}$

true? (Note,I am not sure if I faithfully reproduced his comment)

Also, I was given this problem, and I am wondering if $n=1$ is a mistake. Does the problem make sense if $n$ begins at $1$, rather than $0$?

Comment: It would make sense if the summation started at $n=0$, since $0! = 1! = 1$.

Comment: @copper.hat So, do you suspect that it is a typo?

Comment: Yes. Daniel's comment was with respect to a $n=0$ summation.

Comment: Note that the addition (or subtraction) of a finite number of terms does not affect the radius of convergence.

Comment: I wouldn’t think of using theorems to find the radius of convergence. Just try to evaluate it at a point $\zeta$ of absolute value $1$, and especially at an $m$-th root of unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured out the answer to my question. In order the calculate the radius of convergence $R$, which my book defines as

> $\frac{1}{R} = \lim \sup |c_k|^{1/k}$,

the given power series has to be of the form $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k (z-z_0)^k$. Thus, I want to find $c_k$ for which

> $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k z^k$

holds, as then I will be in a position to calculate $R$ If one expands both sides of the equation, it becomes clear what we need $c_k$ to be in order for this to hold:

> $2z + z^{2!} + z^{3!} + ... = c_0 + c_1 z + c_2 z^2 + ...$

For instance, we need the $z^3$ term to die, and we need $c_1 = 2$, so we need the definition of $c_k$ to be such that $c_3 = 0$ and $c_1 = 2$. And that's how one gets the definition that Daniel Fischer got.

Most may have seen that as obvious, but that's what was confusing. Hopefully it helps others.